# fsck scheduled for reboot - ignored?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, fsck, headless

Recently my server had a power failure which obviously led to hard drive corruption:

```
sudo fsck -n
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warnung!  /dev/mapper/pdc_gahfdjcb2 ist mounted.
Warnung: Überspringe Journal-Wiederherstellung, da das Dateisystem im Nur-Lesen-Modus ist.
/dev/mapper/pdc_gahfdjcb2: sauber, 1716458/91226112 Dateien, 270400467/364881664 Blöcke
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Leaving filesystem unchanged.
[...]
```

For reference, my `fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/pdc_gahfdjcb2 /          ext4  errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota,acl 0       1
/dev/mapper/pdc_gahfdjcb1 /boot/efi  vfat  defaults        0       1
/dev/mapper/pdc_gahfdjcb3 none       swap  sw              0       0
```

As I cannot easily run a live-disk on the server, I wanted to schedule `fsck` for execution on reboot:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo init 6
```

After a reboot, `/forcefsck` has vanished, but the drive is not repaired - the output from `sudo fsck -n` is the same. I suspect that `fsck` has not been started as the boot took way too little time.

Any ideas why `fsck` is presumably not run?